# Where is bitcoin.conf location on MacOS with Bitcoin core v0.15.1

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, mac, bitcoin.conf

After doing some research it is supposed to be under ~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/

But on my computer there is no Bitcoin.conf under ~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin !

So where do I find Bitcoin.conf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitcoin.conf usually arent come with it so you have to make one manually by making a file and naming it `bitcoin.conf`

After you made it, you can use the link below to use the configuration as template

[LINK](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/contrib/debian/examples/bitcoin.conf)

Hope the answer above is what your looking for

Comment: I never installed bitcoin core on Mac so I'm not fully sure but anyway, when you run bitcoin core as first time, it will ask you where to have the data directory located and if you choose the first option then it will save it to the default located overwise it will saved on where you choose it should be

Comment: I know where the data directory is located and it contain wallet.dat ... but not bitcoin.conf

Comment: Ohh next time, please ask your question clear and not just on the title

Comment: Use the new answer i provided

Comment: my data folder is not located under ~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/ does that mean I should create the bitcoin.conf in this path or the data folder path?

Comment: Create a file named bitcoin.conf on where the bitcoin data directory is

Answer (score 0):

by default it goes into the path that you described. If the path was changed, then a search in finder can help. However: search in finder doesn't look into every directory. Try to search for filenames "wallet.dat" or "mempool.dat". Also press the left ALT key, and chose "go to", and select library. Then again do the search in finder. Only then my location was found with the mentioned files. If this doesn't help, open a terminal, and try this:

```
cd /Users
find . -type f -name wallet.dat
```

there might be many Permission denied messages, but it would show, if file was found. If not, there is simply no message. If this still doesn't help, go another directory up ("cd /"), and try again. Time to search will massivly increase then...

Answer (score 0):

Running the Bitcoin core software the first time should create that directory, but then that also loads the mainnet as default. If you don't want that, then you must first manually create the directory and then the Bitcoin.conf file before running the software

i.e

`mkdir  $HOME/Library/Application\ Support/Bitcoin`

`vi $HOME/Library/Application\ Support/Bitcoin/Bitcoin.conf`

Next proceed to open the file and set

```
testnet=1
```

Now run the bitcoin core software to see its now reading from testnet