# Cannot find bitcoin.conf on macOS

Tags: bitcoin-core, mac, bitcoin.conf, error, txindex

I want to run a pruned node. I mistakenly referred to a guide for a full node to connect to Sparrow wallet, which required adding server=1 and txindex=1 in the bitcoin.conf file. I reached this file by opening preferences in the Bitcoin Core menu on a Mac.

Now Bitcoin Core will not run as the error repeatedly appears that a pruned node is incompatible. My issue is I can not locate the bitcoin.conf file in order to remove the txindex=1 or perform whatever fix is necessary. I have attempted the typical paths suggested on all guides for a Mac and cannot find a way to open this file let alone locate it.

I have tried deleting Bitcoin Core and redownloading but the same error appears after opening.

I would love some assistance to figure out how I am able to run my pruned node or at least restart the whole process again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is bitcoin.conf location on MacOS with Bitcoin core v0.15.1](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/69243/where-is-bitcoin-conf-location-on-macos-with-bitcoin-core-v0-15-1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is the data folder for Bitcoin-Qt?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/4006/5406)